# How to protect php/html page so users have to be logged in to view the page

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have a page that I want to protect so people first have to be logged in before they can access the page.

So this is the page you get redirected to when you login (login.php)

```
<?php
// include database.php and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/user.php';
 
// get database.php connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
 
// prepare user object
$user = new User($db);
// set ID property of user to be edited
$user->username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : die();
$user->password = base64_encode(isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : die());
// read the details of user to be edited
$stmt = $user->login();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Login!",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "username" => $row['username']
    );
    header( "refresh:3;url=home.php" );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Username or Password!",
    );
}
// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
?>
```

As you can see if you are logged in you get redirected to "home.php" which is the page I want to protect so you can't directly access it when you know the URL.

So my question is: how do I go about doing this?

Comment: This tutorial might help you get started with login / authentication - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Comment: Also, you can use basic auth to get REALLY basic authentication. Example here - https://gist.github.com/rchrd2/c94eb4701da57ce9a0ad4d2b00794131

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions in PHP, use this on every page where you want to restrict login.

Use this to set session in your loginpage

This is for the login.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];//your username
header( "refresh:3;url=home.php" );//redirect to the page after login
```

This if for other files

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) { //if your username is not set
    header('Location:login.php'); //redirect to loginpage
}
```

Comment: If(!isset()) will never be reached, perhaps answer with the full solution to help the OP